# How to display table from MySQL in Android grid view?

Tags: android

I have been trying to search for on how to display the table from MySQL database in the gridview of android.. But all the example in the internet are based images... I want to display the data from the table as the gridview in asp.... Can anyone help me on this??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Step #1: Write a Web service for your MySQL database, exposing the data you want

Step #2: Have your Android app call out to that Web service, retrieving and parsing the results

Step #3: Display the results in a "table" (`TableLayout`, `GridView`, or whatever you think a "table" is in Android)

Comment: i have no problem on executing the step1 and step2.. but, i dont know how to do execute step3.. can you give some examples on the step3? thanks..